# Cursor indicator in terminal console - out of buffer size

Tags: c++, windows-console

I'm writing a program that prints squares to the screen according to the user's entries, in windows terminal console.

When the cursor
indicator reaches the most bottom right corner of the console and prints a character, it forces a another line in the console, since it moves one place to the right but has no more space.

Any suggestions how to avoid it?

Comment: Find the equivalent of [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for your operating system.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what function in there should help avoid my problem? thanks

Comment: `ncurses` is mostly Linux or Unix specific. It deals with the screen as an two-dimensional array of chars. It won't insert new lines unless you ask it to.

Comment: Use the FillConsoleOutputAttribute() winapi function.

Comment: Could you please give an example that shows how to use this function for my case? I'm very not familiar with console functions. Thanks @HansPassant

Comment: Use Google for that.  Type "fillconsoleoutputattribute example" and take the first hit.